# Using @Transactional and @PostConstruct on same method

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data

I tried to initialize my database using code bellow

```
@Component
public class DataBase {
   @Transactional
   @PostConstruct
   public void init() {
       Query nativeQuery = entityManager.createNativeQuery("Native SQL Query");
       nativeQuery.executeUpdate();
   }
}
```

and I got this runtime exception

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.executeUpdate(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1496) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:380) ~[spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
```

but injecting `DataBase` and calling `init` function is working fine!

```
@Component
public class TestClass {

    @Autowired
    private DataBase dataBase;

    @PostConstruct
    public void test() {
        dataBase.init();
    }
}
```

why this is happening!,is this a bug or there is some reason?

Comment: `@PostContruct` is executed before proxies are created. So an `@Transactional` on `@PostConstruct` doesn't work. Calling it from another `@PostConstruct` method is different as the `Database` needs to be fully initialized before it can be injected into another bean.

Comment: nice point! so where database should be initialized?

Comment: If you want to initialize data after the context has startup create a class implementing `ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>` and initialize there.

Comment: got the same exception while implementing `ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>` and calling `@Transactional init()` method from `onApplicationEvent`

Comment: You shouldn't make that method transactional. You should call transactional methods from the `onApplicationEvent` method.

Comment: I actually did that! look at this https://gist.github.com/mojtabye/50ce47fca1c43263d71b8474b79cdf63

Comment: Calling a transactional method from the same close won't work. Spring uses proxies, you are inside the proxy hence no transactions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178061/discussion-between-mojtabye-and-m-deinum).